# How can I replace'&' to '&amp;' in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, replace

I'm having issues with `.replace()`.  My XML parser does not like '&', but will accept '&\amp;'.  I'd like to use `.replace('&','&amp;')` but this does not seem to be working.  I keep getting the error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 51, column 41
```

So far I have tried just a straight forward `file=file.replace('&','&amp;')`, but this doesn't work.  I've also tried:

```
xml_file = infile
file=xml_file.readlines()
for line in file:
        for char in line:
                char.replace('&','&amp;')
infile=open('a','w')
file='\n'.join(file)
infile.write(file)
infile.close()
infile=open('a','r')
xml_file=infile
```

What would be the best way to fix my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) creates and returns a new string. It can't alter strings in-place - they're immutable. Try replacing:

```
file=xml_file.readlines()
```

with

```
file = [line.replace('&','&amp;') for line in xml_file]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a list equivalent to `.readlines()` but with the replacement already made.

---

As pointed out in the comments, if there were already `&amp;`s in the string, they'd be turned into `&amp;amp;`, likely not what you want. To avoid that, you could use a *negative lookahead* in a regular expression to replace only the ampersands not already followed by `amp;`:

```
import re

file = [re.sub("&(?!amp;)", "&amp;", line) ...]
```

Comment: However, this is a problem if `line` already contains a `&amp;` ...

Comment: @Stefan true enough, I've added an option for that case.

Comment: Awesome! It is still an issue for other escaped stuff like `&lt;` though. I guess this is out of scope for the asked question, but I wanted to mention it. :-)

Comment: Surely there's a function to automatically escape all HTML entities instead of writing your own?

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace()` returns *new string object* with the change made. It does not change data in-place. You are ignoring the return value.

You want to apply it to each line instead:

```
file = [line.replace('&', '&amp;') for line in file]
```

You could use the [`fileinput()` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to do the transformation, and have it handle replacing the original file (a backup will be made):

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input('filename', inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('&', '&amp;'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh...
You need to decode HTML notation for special symbols. Python has module to deal with it - `HTMLParser`, [here some docs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).

Here is example:

```
import HTMLParser

out_file = ....    
file = xml_file.readlines()
parsed_lines = []
for line in file:
     parsed_lines.append(htmlparser.unescape(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic, but it might be good to use some escaping?

I often use urllib's quote which will put the HTML escaping in and out:

```
 result=urllib.quote("filename&fileextension")
 'filename%26fileextension'
 urllib.unquote(result)
 filename&fileextension
```

Might help for consistency?